# Mail Gem: Render received email in browser / Full parse of html parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-gem

I am working with the [Mail Gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) to receive emails in my Rails 4 application.  The mails are grabbed via POP from a mailbox, every 10 minutes or so, via the Gem.

I need to render these emails - mostly in HTML format - and am having trouble saving the body in HTML, not to mention working with things like embedded images.  I'm probably missing something here- looked all over StackOverflow but haven't seen an answer to related questions yet.

I have been working with

```
message.body.decoded
```

and also looked at the html_part v. text_part - but I don't see a method to get to just the enclosed HTML.  Looks like I need to strip the headers, which the Mail Gem seems to leave in the body- then also deal with any inline attachments.  Surely a gem for this must exist..?  Or an approach...? Your advice is valued.

I did find the [Mailcatcher Gem](http://mailcatcher.me/) - but that is really its own Sinatra app. I might just try adapting this gem but that appears to be a lot of work.  Surely someone else has already dealt with this problem..?

I would also value a suggestion on how to best store the message body in MySQL - am thinking large text or blob type.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use [letter opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/)
It works fine... And if you are using [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) as the main development machine you you can use this
[Letter opener web](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web/)